# List of Core Data attribute types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, attributes

I've searched Core Data attribute types but with no success.

When I open my Entity and Attribute there are several types:

1. Integer
2. Double
3. String
4. Boolean

etc.

I'm interested if there is some Apple page which explains about every attribute for which type of usage is.

For example I need an attribute type in which I'll be saving strings of about 1000 characters. Which attribute type do  I use for this type of insert?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NSAttributeDescription` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription) constants section gives:

```
typedef enum {
NSUndefinedAttributeType = 0,
NSInteger16AttributeType = 100,
NSInteger32AttributeType = 200,
NSInteger64AttributeType = 300,
NSDecimalAttributeType = 400,
NSDoubleAttributeType = 500,
NSFloatAttributeType = 600,
NSStringAttributeType = 700,
NSBooleanAttributeType = 800,
NSDateAttributeType = 900,
NSBinaryDataAttributeType = 1000,
NSTransformableAttributeType = 1800,
NSObjectIDAttributeType = 2000
} NSAttributeType;
```

Comment: can you pls tell how much of characters fit in one bit? For now I tkink that I should use attribute type string for inserting string of 1000 characters.

Comment: @CroiOS Using `NSStringAttributeType` looks like the right choice for storing 1000 characters.  Any limitation on the size of each value will probably depend on the underlying storage mechanism.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how much characters fit in 1 bit? (1 character ?)

Comment: @CroiOS No, the only thing that could possibly fit into 1 bit would be a boolean.  A single character would take between 1 and 3 bytes (generally) when encoded using UTF-8 and 2 and 4 bytes when encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: How can I then calculate which attribute type corresponds for which type of insert (from list above with sizes in bits)?

Comment: @CroiOS Those that relate to primitive types are 16-, 32- and 64-bit integers, double would be 64-bit, boolean *could* be 1-bit and the other types are objects derived from `NSObject`, so their size is variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11141/discussion-between-croios-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the list [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription), specifically described in the constants section.

```
Specifically, typedef enum {
NSUndefinedAttributeType = 0,
NSInteger16AttributeType = 100,
NSInteger32AttributeType = 200,
NSInteger64AttributeType = 300,
NSDecimalAttributeType = 400,
NSDoubleAttributeType = 500,
NSFloatAttributeType = 600,
NSStringAttributeType = 700,
NSBooleanAttributeType = 800,
NSDateAttributeType = 900,
NSBinaryDataAttributeType = 1000,
NSTransformableAttributeType = 1800,
NSObjectIDAttributeType = 2000
} NSAttributeType;
```

This means the types available to you are:

**Undefined/transient, short, integer, long, float, double, NSDecimalNumber, NSString, Boolean, NSDate, NSData, Value transformers, and id**

Comment: Is there any link to explanation how many characters fit in for example attribute string?

Comment: @CroiOs - it's unlimited - see sqlite [documentation](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q9).